# BBEDIT multi-fil search : how to add "OR" argument in the find window?

Tags: arguments, bbedit

Hi trying out latest BBedit on Ventura Apple silicon.

Have been wrapping my head around the (im)possibility to search for different strings at once in the find window, in order to have each occurrence replaced by one single term.

I would like something like this :

Find : string 1 OR string 2 OR string 3

Replace : string 4.

In the manual it seems this should be possible with the straight bar | but that didn't find anything at all.

I'm sure this must be possible but am unable to find out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that the pipe symbol acts as OR.
e.g. `string1|string2|string3`
It's a common usage, but BBEdit doesn't use it until you switch on 'grep'

Off…
[image]

On…
[image]

Once enabled, then Replace will work as you expected.

[image]

<sup>using random rtf file with my 'what to watch on TV' list ;))</sup>

Comment: ok so that's the culprit !!! I had tried exactly that syntax without having Grep checked... Thanks a lot for the quick reply (sparing me hours of work) !

As a follow-up question : is it possible to have a given set of different entries with different answers in the Find field or is it one category by one.

I mean :
if string 1 or 2 or 3 then replace by string 4
if string A or B or C then replace by string D

could this be done in a single step or must i do different search&replace operations to be able to achieve that ?

Comment: Excellent! Remember to check the grey checkmark ✔ left of this answer to turn it green [it might make you wait some time, as a new user]. That way future googlers will be better able to find it.

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question - it would need to support an ELSE logic. I'm not sure it does.

Comment: ok will do thanks !

Answer (score 0):

BBedit supports PCRE regular expressions.

Your search expression will look like :

```
string1|string2|string3
```

Reference :
[PCRE Regex Cheatsheet](https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/pcre).